# Re-shuffle the words to accommodate max words in a single line and create less number of lines using Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist, logic

Re-shuffle the words to accommodate max words in a single line of size 42 characters and create less number of lines using Java

I have to create comma separated words and max size of a line is 42.
The strings could be re-shuffle in such a way to accommodate max words without crossing line size 42 and within less number of lines.
To achieve this I have sorted the words based on it's length.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ManageWords {
private static final int LINE_MAX_SIZE = 45;

public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
wordList.add("URUNDI");
wordList.add("AFGHANISTAN");
wordList.add("WEST GERMANY");
wordList.add("ALAND ISLANDS");
wordList.add("VIET-NAM - DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF");

Collections.sort(wordList, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
List<String> concatenatedWordsLines = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
String concatenatedWords = wordList.get(i);
int j = i + 1;

if (concatenatedWords.length() < LINE_MAX_SIZE) {
while (concatenatedWords.length() < LINE_MAX_SIZE && j <= wordList.size() - 1) {
if (concatenatedWords.concat("," + wordList.get(j)).length() < LINE_MAX_SIZE) {
concatenatedWords = concatenatedWords.concat("," + wordList.get(j));
} else {
break;
}
j++;
}

concatenatedWordsLines.add(concatenatedWords);
i = j - 1;
}
}

for (String s : concatenatedWordsLines) {
System.out.println(s + " : " + s.length());
}
}
}
```

With above code I am getting below result with 3 lines,

```
 
    URUNDI,AFGHANISTAN,WEST GERMANY
    ALAND ISLANDS
    VIET-NAM - DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF
```

Whereas I am expecting it in 2 lines which size is less than or equal to 42 like below,

```
 
    URUNDI,VIET-NAM - DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF
    AFGHANISTAN,WEST GERMANY,ALAND ISLANDS
```

The purpose is to accommodate all words with minimum possible lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a variant of the [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). It is a NP-hard problem, so unless your input is very small, trying to find an optimal solution might not be feasible.

There are several ways to solve it:

- You can go for a [first-fit greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) (easy to implement, can give decent results in many cases). It is a 2-approximation of the problem, so in the worst case you'll have twice more lines than the best possible solution.
- You can also implement a brute force algorithm (test all the possible combination using an enumeration algorithm, fits only very small inputs but finds an optimal solution).
- Another possibility using java would be to plug it with the [Cplex solver](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/cplex-optimizer) (or any other [ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) solver) using an interface like [Ilog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/package-summary.html).

  IMHO, the ILP approach should be favored, since it is a useful tool to learn using, the programs will be quite simple to write once you're done with the interfacing part, and it is already optimized and will return you an optimal answer on small instances, and a good feasible solution for non-tractable instances.